# Heroku No such file or directory in /app/index.php on line 4

Tags: php, heroku, runtime-error, cleardb

```
2018-08-26T11:53:04.010859+00:00 app[web.1]: [26-Aug-2018 11:53:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(Connect/Connect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/index.php on line 4
2018-08-26T11:53:04.011186+00:00 app[web.1]: [26-Aug-2018 11:53:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Connect/Connect.php' (include_path='.:/app/.heroku/php/lib/php') in /app/index.php on line 4
2018-08-26T11:53:04.011508+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.147.20.4 - - [26/Aug/2018:11:53:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
```

This is the error showing can't find the problem please help.
I changed the connect/connect.php code to

```
<?php
$url = parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));
$server = $url["host"];
$username = $url["user"];
$password = $url["pass"];
$conn = substr($url["path"], 1);
$db = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $conn);
?>
```

and linked it in index.php as

```
<?php
require'Connect/Connect.php';
?>
```